# Error while running snmpget from net-snmp C package

Tags: c, openwrt, net-snmp

I have written a C-program using net-snmp C package. When I run that program on my laptop, I get the result alright. But when I run the same program on Cloudgate (an openwrt enabled gateway device), I get the following error along with my reuslt

> No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
>
> Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
>
> Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

How should I handle it?

P.S. I am installing net-snmp in that device using makefile from the site

​https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/net/net-snmp/Makefile?rev=25486

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to stop this error from popping would be to create an **snmp.conf** file in */etc/snmp* folder (if it is not created already) and add the following line

```
mibs :
```

it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the missing MIBs specified in the error message, or disable MIB errors with [the appropriate option](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpcmd.html#lbAG):

```
snmpget -Pe ...
```

Comment: actually I solved the issue. Turns out net-snmp does not create a snmp.conf file by default when the package is installed in openwrt environment. I just created an snmp.conf file with one entry mibs and the error stopped popping. Anyways thanks for your time

Comment: Then you should delete your question, or post your own answer.